# Tableau Adding Subtotal

Tags: tableau-api

I have a detailed report that displays the individual Survey Score (in percentage), and enabled the subtotal to Average the Score per Manager, but total is blank. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Blue pills in tableau stand for dimensions, so tableau does not see any measure to calculate totals.
Put SUM(Score ...) on Label (Text) mark and make it continious